# How susceptible is the greater Seattle area to an wildland-urban interface conflagration like the Camp Fire or 1991 Oakland firestorm?

Tags: forest, natural-disasters, wildfire, fire

Is there the risk of an "Issaquah firestorm", something with the intensity of Tyee Creek or Thirtymile but hitting suburban areas of the Cascade foothills like Issaquah, Samammish, Cougar Mountain?

Comment: Note that [Firestorm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firestorm) has a specific meaning (I don't know what Tyee Creek or Thirtymile are or whether those had actual firestorms).

Comment: Couldn't find a Wikipedia article for the Tyee Creek fire, but it burned 135,000 acres in Chelan County in the summer of 1994, at the time it was the largest wildfire in the state since the Great Fire of 1910. Thirtymile fire: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thirtymile_Fire

Comment: I just used the term "firestorm" as an analogy to the Oakland firestorm, a wildland-urban interface conflagration driven by embers. I didn't know it was an actual scientific term, I guess I learn something new every day.